# How to handle " Helm Upgrade Timeout" error?

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I am trying to do a helm upgrade and I am getting the following error:
`Error: UPGRADE FAILED: timed out waiting for the condition`. The command ran is thus: `helm upgrade releaseoup --wait . -n releaseoup`.

I have no idea what could be the problem because `kubectl` interacts with the cluster comfortably `helm upgrade` timeout is very strange. By the way, this is not a first deployment so it once worked with same commands, I just need to do an upgrade to a new version.

Can anybody help please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 6):

The [doc](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_upgrade/) says `helm upgrade` has a default timeout `5m`. It is very common that you may need set a longer timeout.

*example*

```sh
helm upgrade --wait --timeout=1h
```